# Importing libs with __init__.py

Tags: python

Why does my namespace import not work when I use the os.chdir() to get to the package dir from script?

For example here is my package structure to demonstrate the problem.

```
testpk/
testpk/bin
testpk/bin/runit.py
testpk/lib
testpk/lib/libcode.py
testpk/lib/__init__.py
```

here is my lib code which just prints ive been imported

```
print "I've been imported"
```

contents of runit.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import  sys, os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.chdir('/home/moorepe/src/testpk')   
    print "working path = " , os.getcwd()
    import lib.libcode
```

If i run runit i get this error:

```
moorepe@halifax$ bin/runit.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/runit.py", line 6, in <module>
    import lib.libcode 
ImportError: No module named lib.libcode
```

However testing this with python command line it works as expected:

```
    cd testpk
    python -c "import lib.libcode
    I've been imported
```

And this works from the bin dir:

```
cd testpk/bin
python -c "import os; os.chdir('/home/moorepe/src/testpk') ; import lib.libcode"
I've been imported
```

Can anyone explain what is going wrong?

So the reason this didnt work is that python uses the current dir as a path in addition to the PYTHONPATH.

so this code works by adding sys.path.append(".") because im forcing a current working dir as a path addition.

Comment: Im guessing `lib.libcode` isn't in your path

Comment: Why are you doing this chdir?

Comment: @Keith I didnt want to fuzz up the subject with why but I need to have test code find lib its supposed to unittest, the main code use the lib code with namespaces properly, and have deploy code only deploy the bin and lib code.

Comment: @JakobBowyer The the path is not needed if `__init__.py` is in the lib dir. if i do a chdir() to the package base then all this should work. And as i show with the last python command line it does. it just dosnt work in the runit.py

Comment: Why is there not output from the `print "working path = " , os.getcwd()` statement in `runit.py` shown in your stacktrace from the error?

Comment: @martineau Yes i did pull that line out to condense the example further. My apologies.

Comment: Why do you even mess with the paths in your application? Why don’t use use relative imports and make the program portable that way?

Comment: @poke Can you demonstrate what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `'.'` for the current directory to the `sys.path` search folder list, then the `os.chdir()` will become effective and the `import lib.libcode` should start working:

File **`runit.py`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import  sys, os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.path[0:0] = ['.']  # prefix current directory to list
    os.chdir('/home/moorepe/src/testpk')
    print "working path =", os.getcwd()
    import lib.libcode
```

Comment: It's customary to also up-vote the answer you accept if you think it's worthy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that I've found to work:

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib') )

#from pprint import pprint as pp
#pp(sys.path)
import libcode
```

That way, it doesn't look like your top-level library name is `lib`, but rather `libcode`.

### The "Official" (*Pythonic*) Way

If you're creating a python module, you might want to look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).  They recommend using `__init__.py` along with a directory structure that matches your module's  [organizational structure](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) (This seems to be the *"Pythonic"* way to do things).  Although any traditional *Ruby-ish* or *Java-ish* `lib` directory structure feasibly works as long as you understand the module load path and set it appropriately so your module is loadable.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that testpk/lib/ is in your `PYTHONPATH`.

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/testpk/lib/')
```

is an ugly way of ensuring that your package is in your `PYTHONPATH`.

The "correct way" to do it is to place your `testpk` package and all its sub-directories in your Python `site-packages` directory.

To find out where your `site-packages` (which should be in your `PYTHONPATH`) is.

```
GET_PYTHON_LIB_CMD="from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print (get_python_lib())"
python -c "$GET_PYTHON_LIB_CMD"
```

will give you the location.

Comment: I dont agree with either of these statements. But you actually made me think of why it doesnt work.
i need `sys.path.append('.')`

Comment: `sys.path.append('.')` adds your current location to `PYTHONPATH`.  It's essentially the same thing. The key is to ensure that `/whatever/path/to/lib` is in `PYTHONPATH` because you are trying to import that into your running code. When we install 3rd party python libraries via `pip install [python_library_from_pypi]`, what we are in fact doing is downloading the python package from pypi, and once downloaded, the package's `setup.py` file will run and pace the package in `site-packages`, which makes it available in `PYTHONPATH` and hence available for imports.

Comment: That is true but i didnt want specific paths to be added. I wanted it to work as presented. I just didnt know why the command line action `python -c "import os; os.chdir('/home/moorepe/src/testpk') ; import lib.libcode"` worked when my runit.py didnt.

Comment: So I was confounded as to why the command function `python -c "import os; os.chdir('/home/moorepe/src/testpk') ; import lib.libcode"` worked in the bin dir. It turns out that when you run python in a one liner you have an extra path which is always '' in sys.path and this is the current working dir. When you run the script you have the current directory of the script '/home/moorepe/src/testpk/bin'. This caused my confusion as to why there was different behavior.

Comment: Yes. os.chdir changes your directory but it still doesn't solve the underlying problem - which is a need to have the library you are importing in PYTHONPATH ("sys.path").

Answer (score 0):

From a given script, if you want to add a library to its sys.path relative to the script itself, you can add the location the library computing its location from where the script is, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# testpk/bin/runit.py
import os
import sys
_op = os.path
# if file is referred to by symlink, make __file__ point to it's actual location
__file__ = _op.realpath(__file__)
# add __file__'s directory's parent directory to the path
sys.path.append(_op.abspath(_op.join(_op.dirname(__file__), "..")))
import lib

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then you can call your executable from where ever:

```
% pwd
/tmp
% ./testpk/bin/runit.py 
I've been imported
```

Since I accounted for running the script via symlink in my re-assignment of `__file__`, I an even do this:

```
% pwd
/tmp
% ln -s ./testpk/bin/runit.py 
% ./runit.py 
I've been imported
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem was solved by adding `sys.path.append('.')` to the runit.py before my chdir. This is more elegant than to explicitly adding a package path and then doing a chdir to whatever context in our package you need to test. Then your unittests are always in context to the current directory.